# Animation dependent on previous page (via link)

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript and I'm trying to figure out a way to trigger a keyframe animation if the page is accessed via a link on a menu page.
The code I have come up with so far using `document.referrer` does not work:

```js
var ref = document.referrer; 
if (ref.includes("menu")) {
    document.getElementById('symbol').style.animation=' 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideLogo';
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The script is located at the end of `<body>` and runs nicely when ref is changed to a statement containing the search word.
I'm currently only testing locally, could that be why?

Comment: Have you determined whether `ref.includes("menu")` is true, perhaps by adding an `alert` call in your `if` block?

Comment: If you add `alert('setting style value');` inside your `if` block, then at least you will know whether `document.referrer` is doing what you expect, based on whether you see the alert message when you load the page. Then you can move on to the next step of debugging.

Comment: What is the value of document.referrer? If you `alert` that are you seeing "menu" in there at all?

Comment: Alert comes up empty. I believe this must be due to document.referrer only showing http sources (but I can't find any confirmation for this?). I won't get to test this now, but will do so later and post my findings here.

Comment: Yes, I believe referrer is suppressed for `file://`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is going wrong without seeing the rest of the code, but the following should work.

Save as `landing.html`

```
<style type="text/css">
    #symbol {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    @keyframes slideLogo { from { margin-left: -20%; } to { margin-left: 100%; }  }

</style>

<h1>Landing page</h1>

<div id="symbol"></div>

<script>
    var ref = document.referrer; 
    console.log('referrer is', ref);
    if (ref.includes("menu")) {
        console.log('set the style.animation property');
        document.getElementById('symbol').style.animation=' 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideLogo';
    }
    else {
        console.log('DO NOT set the style.animation property');
    }
</script>
```

Put a link to landing.html in a file called `menu.html`. And make sure you're accessing it via something like `http://localhost/menu.html`

Similarly, put a link to landing.html in a file that will not have "menu" anywhere in the url, e.g.`http://localhost/something-else.html`. This will not trigger the animation.

So if these 3 files are accessed by their filenames, then the link from `http://localhost/menu.html` will trigger the animation on `http://localhost/landing.html`

It's worth noting that your referrer test will look anywhere in the referrer url, so even partial matches like `http://localhost/not-a-menu.html` will trigger the animation. So you may want to make your test a little more specific if you're worried about this.

Also, for browser compatibility, I think at this point it is still a little safer to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead of [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

`if(document.referrer.indexOf('menu') !== -1) { ... }`